# How to use \includeonlyframes with textblock? (All pages are printed)

Tags: beamer, textpos

All pages are printed. How to solve it?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\includeonlyframes{current}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\addbibresource{ppgeq.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=current]
  Slide 1
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  Slide 2

\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(9cm,2.5cm) % {block width} (coords)
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image.png}
\end{textblock*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the frame containing your `textblock` a `label` that is not used as part of your `\includeonlyframes` list:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\includeonlyframes{current}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=current]
  Slide 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=notcurrent]
  Slide 2

  \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(9cm,2.5cm) % {block width} (coords)
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
  \end{textblock*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The above produces a single frame (Slide 1).

---

The following [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch provides a default (unique) `label` to each frame, which can be overwritten using the `label=<label>` key. This way `\includeonlyframes` still works as expected:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@@@@frame}% <cmd>
  {\setkeys{beamerframe}{#2}}% <search>
  {\edef\theframe{\number\numexpr\value{framenumber}+1}%
   \setkeys{beamerframe}{label=frame-\theframe,#2}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

Comment: So how to give a default label? I have many slides...

Comment: @Vitor: See the updated answer.